# How to declare a new array for each player - during a for loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration

I have a finite number of players the user inputs, and I have to make a one-dimension array (always with 5 members) for each player. How can I do it (I need to be able to use these arrays later outside the loop). Oh and I can't use lists.

Something like this:

```
for (int player =1;player<=participants;player++)
{
int matrixnum[] = new int [5];
}
```

and somehow to make it change each iteration to `matrixnum1`, `matrixnum2`... `matrixnumparticipants`.

Comment: No. A project for a beginner learning alone.

Comment: You mean an *arbitrarily large* but *finite* number of players, right? An infinite number of players is rather too many.

Comment: thanks Eric for the comment - of course I meant a finite number and actually not so large (2-15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So each player needs its own array? You should create a class `Player` that has an array of `int`s:

```
public class Player {
  public int[] values;

  public Player() {
    values = new int[5];
  }
}

public class Main {
  ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int player = 1; player < participants; player++) {
      players.add(new Player());
    }
  }
}
```

Doing this allows you to add a method to the `Player` class to make modifying and using the arrays easier.

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment on another answer, where you don't want to use classes, you should use an `ArrayList` of `int` arrays.

```
ArrayList<int[]> matrix = new ArrayList<int[]>();

for(int player = 1; player < participants; player++) {
  matrix.add(new int[5]);
}
```

This lets you add and remove players freely later on.

And when you need to get an individual player's array:

```
int[] somePlayer = matrix.get(indexOfPlayer);
```

[Read more about `ArrayList`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you have questions.

Comment: Ok, and how can I separate them into different arrays later on?

Comment: Which is the namespace for ArrayList<T> in .net? The non-generic type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @drdigit: I believe Jon meant to say "List<T>" not "ArrayList<T>".

Comment: Absolutely not. matrix is defined as ArrayList<int[]>) which is java and is proved by the matrix.get(indexOfPlayer) method. The answer is wrong for C#!

Comment: @drdigit also note that the linked documentation is for java.  However, if you substitute `List<T>` and `matrix[indexOfPlayer]`, you'll get what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I agree up to a point. I ask in English and you answer in French :) In any case the best approach is to use a jagged array, that can be more flexible if you define it as a List<List<int>> as it can cover any possible change in specs relating to jagged array dimensions.

Comment: @drdigit That's true, but the OP stated that there will always be 5 elements in the inner array, so I found that a "waste of resources" if you will.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
List<List<int>> jagged = new List<List<int>>(maxParticipals /* optional */);
int participants = 0;
int finite = 15;
```

and move on with something like this

```
void more(int value)
{
    participants = value;
    while (jagged.Count < participants) jagged.Add(new List<int>(finite));
}
```

or this

```
void add(int newOnes)
{
    participants += newOnes;
    while (jagged.Count < participants) jagged.Add(new List<int>(finite));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

First create a class for a player with all its info:

```
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name;
        //etc
    }
```

The create a class to manage the operation Add:

```
   public class PlayersManager
   {
     private readonly Player[,] _players;
     private readonly int _totalNumberOfPlayers;
     private readonly int _topNumberOfTeams;

     private bool PlayerPositionReachedLimit {
        get { return _playerPosition == _topNumberOfTeams; }
     }

     private bool PlayerCounterExcedsTotalPlayers
     {
        get { return _playerCounter >= _totalNumberOfPlayers; }
     }

     private int _playerCounter;
     private int _playerPosition;

    public Player[,] Players
    {
        get { return _players; }
    }

    public PlayersManager(int totalNumberOfPlayers, int topNumberOfTeams)
    {
        _playerCounter = 0;
        _playerPosition = 0;
        _topNumberOfTeams = topNumberOfTeams;
        _totalNumberOfPlayers = totalNumberOfPlayers;
        _players = new Player[totalNumberOfPlayers, topNumberOfTeams];
    }

    public void Add(Player player)
    {
        if (PlayerCounterExcedsTotalPlayers)
          throw new Exception("Number of players exceded");
        if (PlayerPositionReachedLimit)
        {
            _playerCounter++;
            _playerPosition = 0;
        }
        _players[_playerCounter, _playerPosition]= player;

        _playerPosition++;
    }
}
```

So the you could do something like:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void PruebaPlayersManager()
    {
        var playersManager = new PlayersManager(2, 5);

        for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            var player = new Player
                             {
                                 Name = i.ToString()
                             };
            playersManager.Add(player);
        }
    }
```

And Now your not limited to just 5, you can configure it to any size you want :)

I hope this helps,

Cheers